# Data isn't received

Tags: java, android, android-intent, toast

I wrote android code to send data that taken from textbox from one activity to appear in Toast message in another activity in the same project

and this is code

the code of main activity is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str = txt.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Target.class);
            i.putExtra("Name", str);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

and the code of target activity is

```
public void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_target);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = b.getString("Name");
    Toast.makeText(Target.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

when I run the project and write something in textbox and press the button
the other activity is opened and nothing happened.

can you help me and tell me why this problem occurred?

Comment: Please check if the value of "Name" is received in the Target Activity and if it's the same as the text you input into the EditText. You can do this by using: Log.d("Target Activity", "String received in Target = "+s); and put this code right before your toast. Let me know if it matches the Log message matches the EditText you sent.

Comment: I don't know what this function "Log.d()" do, but I try what you say but no thing happen

Comment: the Log.d() displays a message in the LogCat view.. you can use this to check if the "Name" extras is received

Comment: thank you A.A for information

Comment: dear Vishwa Patel, I tried this function again,
it seems the value of "Name" doesn't received in the Target Activity

Comment: Try removing the Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); and just use String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name"); and then use Log.d("Target Activity", "Name = "+s);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem, small typo

```
public void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

should be

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

missing `e` :)

It will not override the super class `onCreate`, though it is a valid function. But never be called.

Comment: I hate letter 'e' :(
thank you alot mr so geek
the problem solved :D